# subset values in a df based on values in another df

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dataframe, subset

I have two dfs, both dim `[1]  54 210`. One (lets call it `dfx`) contains 1, 0s to mark incorrect and correct answers on a test. `dfy` contains the response time for each of these questions. I'd like to subset(`merge()` (perhaps) all items from `dfy` that are == 1 in `dfx`. The data is in the wide format, ID = rownames and columns represent each question.

Example:

dfx

```
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 …
1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  1  1 
1  1  0  1  1
```

Dfy

```
Q1_3 Q2_3  Q3_3  Q4_3  Q5_3 ...
16.01 8.23 18.13 11.14 18.03
17.25 7.50 11.72 10.84  7.24
```

I would need a dfz that is a subset of dfy, in which if `dfx[Q1] == 1`, `dfy [Q1_3]` is returned as `dfz[Q1_3]`, otherwise `NA` or `dfx[Q1]`( which is 0).

I can do it if I specify cols by

```
dfz<- cbind(ifelse(dfx$Q1 == 1, dfy$Q1_3, dfx$Q1))
```

however I don't know how to apply it for the whole df.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an unique identifier in your data frames (I mean, like an `id` column that let's you match each row in `dfx` with a row in `dfy`)? Or, are you ensuring that the order of the rows matches for both data frames?

Comment: @Barranka : I can insert an id column, however rownames == for both dfs

Comment: It can be something as simple as `dfy * dfx`. If dfx has only ones and zeros, the product of both will return zero for non correct answers and the value of `dfy` for correct ones.

Comment: OMG @Barranka :) that does solve my question, yes :) However, would you know how to transform this:
`dfz<- cbind(ifelse(dfx$Q1 == 1, dfy$Q1_3, dfx$Q1))` into a function so I can manipulate dfs based on values in another?

Comment: Check my answer... it may help you (it includes my above comment, so you can upvote or accept it, if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both data frames have the same size, and `dfx` has only ones and zeros, you can multiply them to get what you need:

```
dfz <- dfy * dfx
```

---

On your next comment, you ask how can you manipulate columns from a dataframe based on the values of other data frame. I frequently use the [`sqldf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) for this kind of thing. It let's you manipulate dataframes using SQL instructions. You'll need some `id` column that let's you relate your dataframes.

A simple example:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select df_a.id
            , case
                  when df_b.q1 = 1 then df_a.q1
                  else 0
              end as value
       from df_a
            inner join df_b on df_a.id = df_b.id")
```

As you can see, you can join dataframes as if they were tables in a database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that really makes sense. I am just barely getting familiar with R and I cannot do SQL, but I see the logic in it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @CsabaSzavo Happy to help. There are lots of online resources for learning R. I recommend you [The Quick-R Tutorial](http://statmethods.net). (By the way, if you think this answer was useful, up-vote it, and/or accept it ;-) )

Comment: cannot upvote yet, but I accepted the answer... :) thanks